# How to select multiple entries from seperate database and add to current database (admin side)

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to now upgrade my database and having a little bit of difficulty.

Below is my models.py file

```
class artists(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="artist",default= "artistsdefault")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class song(models.Model):

song_youtube_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,default= "urldefault")

song_num = models.IntegerField(default= 0 )

song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default= "titledefault")

artists_included = models.ForeignKey(artists, verbose_name="artists",on_delete=models.CASCADE,default= "artists")
```

The above works but when I manually add a song class in the admin backend I can only select 1 artist included from a drop-down list?

[image: View of the admin page where I would like to select multiple artists instead of just 1 from the dropdown]

I would like to be able to select multiple artists and save to the song database by selecting multiple artists from the drop-down not just one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use manytomanyfield instead of foreign key.

Here is the link for your reference:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create a custom form and use that form in your admin.

For Example:-

forms.py

class ArtistSongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    artist = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ArtistSongForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['artists_included'].choices = artists.objects.values_list('id','name')
    class Meta:
        model=song

admin.py

class ArtistSongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form  = ArtistSongForm
admin.site.register(song, ArtistSongAdmin)
```